# How to keep background image size on iPad

Tags: css, html, ipad

I have a 2px X 4px background image on my website and it repeats through X and Y.

When I view it on iPad, the background shrinks or something, it just looks burled. How can I keep it clear and achieve 2px X 4px on iPad? Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

The blurring is most likely being caused by the iPad retina display trying to upscale your small background image. Same thing happens on iPhone 4 vs iPhone 3, as well as newer android devices. Use the following code in your CSS to fix that. You will need a 2px by 4px image as your original background, along with that same image at double resolution (4px by 8px). The `@media` query allows you to resize your @2x version of the image, then 'shrink' it back down to the intended size with `background-size: 4px;` in the css.

```
body {
    background: url(test-image.png) repeat;
}

@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
       only screen and (-moz-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
       only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),
       only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
           body {background: url(test-image@2x.png) repeat; background-size: 4px;}
}
```

I've tested this snippet on my iPad retina and it fixed the blurring. I hope this helps you out, let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Hi. Thanks. But this trick didnt work. I think the iPad is still using the 2X4 image

Comment: Using `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">` fixed it. But I dont get what that does. But I cant pinch and zoom

Answer (score 0):

Ok This if what I did.

Set view port to

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

and that fixed  the image issue. But I cant zoom in and out anymore. But its not necessary for this project. :) Thanks for the help

Comment: I had assumed you were already using that on your page, I apologize. I am glad you were able to get it fixed :)